# How can I duplicate python 2 chr exactly in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi I am trying to migrate some code to python 3 but am having the following problem.

Python 2

```
>>> a = chr(217)
>>> print a, type(a)
� <type 'str'>
```

Python 3

```
>>> a = chr(217)
>>> print(a, type(a))
Ù <class 'str'>
```

The reason is that I have Existing data created with the following code

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES

fle = open("data.dat", "wt")
key = "password000*****"
pwd = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_ECB)
for dat in ("dataname001*****", "dataname002*****"):
    txt = ""
    hsh = pwd.encrypt(dat)
    for c in hsh:
        txt = txt + str(ord(c)) + ","
    fle.write("%s\n" % txt[:-1])
fle.close()
```

I need to read the data which I can do using python2 but not python3

```
fle = open("data.dat", "rt")
for dat in fle:
    txt = ""
    for c in dat.split(","):
        txt = txt + chr(int(c))
    print(pwd.decrypt(txt))
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 4):

[`chr` in Python3.x](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#chr) is similar to [`unichr` in Python 2.x](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#unichr).

If you want a byte string, use [`bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#bytes):

```
>>> bytes([217])
b'\xd9'
```

or [`bytearray`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#bytearray):

```
>>> bytearray([217])
bytearray(b'\xd9')
```

Answer (score 1):

That *is* an exact duplication. For certain definitions of "exact".

The differences you see are:

1. The `chr()` in Python 3 is actually the Python 2 `unichr()`. This is probably why the character now is printed correctly.
2. "Types" is an old thing from way back in Python before 2.2. The `str` class is called "type" in Python 2 for backwards compatibility reasons. It's now called "class" just like all other classes.

There are also a difference you do not see:

3. The Python 2 and Python 3 `str` class are not entirely compatible. The Python 3 one is actually more like Python 2's `unicode` class. But this is not a relevant difference in your example.

Answer (score -1):

To add another view on why it may not work as expected. The number used as a parameter of `chr` in Python 3 is expected to be a Unicode code point. Now it depends on how the `data.dat` content was encoded during writing and how it is decoded when reading back.

I have noticed, that you are reading the file in a text mode. Then, in Python 2, you may want to use the standard Python 2 module [`codecs`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html) to read the content correctly. Possibly, use [`codecs.open()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#codecs.open) instead of the plain `open()`.

Comment: The whole point is that it works perfectly in python 2. It is not working in python 3.

Comment: I see. I did not use the `Crypto` module, but it probably works with bytes, does it? If yes, you must use `bytes` type variables in Python 3, and you have to open the `data.dat` file in a binary mode (like "wb" and "rb"). The `bytes` type is the type that actually is the Python 2 `str` type. But it is just my guess.